# express routes give fialed (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) in electron app after deployment

Tags: node.js, express, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an `electron` that also run an `express` app.
in `development` mode everything works fine but after deployment and install app, express routes is not working.
[image: screenshot]

```
//package.json
{
  "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      "./extraResources/**"
    ]
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder -w",
    "build:gyp": "node-gyp rebuild"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^20.1.4",
    "electron-builder": "^23.3.3",
    "node-gyp": "^9.1.0"
  },

}
```

```js
//main.js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
let server = require('./nodejs/server');  // this is express app
function createWindow () {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
      }
    })
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join( __dirname, '/front/index.html'));
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => app.quit());
  

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})
```

I see with `console.log()` that `express` app is running in `dev` mode correctly.
but in `production` all apis fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case after I build and start my app, environment variables inside `.env` file are `undefiend`. so app does not start correctly.